# Shoutem Changing main background on App

Tags: shoutem

I want to upload an image and set that to the background on my custom shoutem app. I've seen some tutorials where this is possible in the builder but it appears to be for the older version. Do I need to create a custom theme to accomplish this? If so where do i need to set the background in the theme.js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way right way to do it is to [modify](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/modifying-extensions) Shoutem [navigation extension](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/tree/master/shoutem-navigation). Let's say that you're using `TabBar` navigation: in that case, you should customize [TabBar](https://github.com/shoutem/extensions/blob/master/shoutem-navigation/app/screens/TabBar.js) screen and render an `Image` component on top of the `Screen` component. Also, you need to put transparent color as value for the background color in `Style` -> `Customize theme` -> `Background color` under `Basic color`.